# Assigning Fogbugz cases programmatically

Tags: fogbugz

I want to write an application that assigns Fogbugz cases programmatically, how would I accomplish this? Is it possible to achieve this given any of the following scenarios:

- The user enters text in my
  application's input field and the
  Fogbugz report is opened in the
  browser where the "note" field is
  populated with the text from the user
  input
- The fogbugz report is assigned to the
  specified user in the application
  without the browser even being opened
  i.e. the report is stored directly in
  the DB.

I'm planning to add default values to the other fields as well so I would assume the process would be the same for adding text to the "note" field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [Fogbugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html). See the heading "Editing Cases" for the specifics on how to edit a case (which includes creating a new one). It's a little complicated (or perhaps just oddly designed) but, as I remember, you basically have to call cmd=new if you want to create a new case, supply your text in the 's' parameter and set the ixPersonAssignedTo to the correct person.  For an existing case, use cmd=edit.

This is possible both with a regular form posted to your Fogbugz installation and some server side code that calls the API.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a plugin for FB and allow others to use it.  (share it or sell it)